# How to execute Google App script from external script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am attempting to build a web app that will create a Google Doc from a template and populate it with user provided data. Using Google's quickstart example in the documentation, I can successfully authorize and access the Google Drive file system. Now I need to programmatically open a template Google Doc (or even create one from scratch) and add the data.

This is rather easily done using App Script's Document Service (the `DocumentApp`class). So I can do something like:

```
function createDoc(contentArray) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = contentArray; // data submitted with HTML form passed as arg
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

in a standalone App Script and successfully create the new Google Doc on Google Drive. I can't figure out how to execute this App Script from my external web app. Is there a way to do this or do I need to find a different way to create Google Docs (and add content) using just the Drive API?

**EDIT:**

here is the GET request from my web app:

```
var gurl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwMHKzfZr1X06zP2iEB4E8Vh-U1vGahaLjXZA1tk49tBNf0xk4/exec";
$.get(
    gurl,
    { name: "john", time: "2pm",},
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    "jsonp"
)
```

and here is my `doGet()`:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var result = "";
  var name = e.parameter.name;

  Logger.log(name);

  try {
    result = "Hello " + name;
  } catch (f) {
    result = "Error: " + f.toString();
  }

  result = JSON.stringify({
    "result": result
  });  

  var doc = DocumentApp.create('ballz3');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat'], ['Moss', 'Frog']];
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
  Logger.log('DOc Name: ' + doc.getName());

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);   

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) - to be able to execute your webapp, you'll need a `doGet()` or a `doPost()` function and a versioned deployment of your WebApp

Comment: @oleg valter this is exactly what i need. I can successfully handle a request (with `doGet()` or `doPost()` and send back a response, but it doesn't seem to be executing any of my `Document.app` calls. Possibly a permissions thing?

Comment: You have to deploy the script webapp with the following parameters: execute as me and accessible to anyone even anonymous. That's because when your app is calling the doget function via the URL it is actually anonymous.

Comment: If you think it would create a security issue you can imagine a couple of security parameters to make it really difficult to hack. The documentation shows how to add parameters to an URL and how to handle it in a doget function. I've used that configuration a lot of time to(for example) restrict the access to certain people in my domain by giving each one of them an unique url.

Comment: @Daveh0, sorry saw your question only now - I believe Serge answered your question in full, it is indeed a permissions issue (enable anonymous access). Or you can take an *API executable* route as Alberto suggested (both have their pros & cons, ofc)

Comment: @Serge Insas & oleg valter - those are the exact parameters I'm using. like I said, the script is handling the request and sending a proper response. It just doesn't appear that any of my document service code is being executed when I make my request from my web app - see script in OP. If i run the app script url in a browser, that code DOES get executed

Comment: @Daveh0 I think that in your Javascript, the response value cannot be retrieved because of an error, while the script of Web Apps is run. If you want to retrieve the response value from Web Apps, how about modifying from ``"jsonp"`` to ``"json"``? If this was not the result you want, I apologize. By the way, when you modified Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please deploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.

Comment: @Tanaike - I am successfully getting the response back in my web app, so i don't believe there are any errors. `jsonp` and setting the MIME type to javascript is necessary otherwise COORS errors occur. And yes, I've confirmed that I have been redeploying script after changes.

Comment: @Daveh0 Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. For example, how about returning ``json`` instead of the response of ``jsonp``? It's like ``return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)``

Comment: @Tanaike - when I do that, I do not get any errors, but my Document Service code is not executed AND I do not get a response... no errors, but no response data at all.

Comment: @Daveh0 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested your current script in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. Google Document ("ballz3") including a table is created and ``{result: "Hello john"}`` is returned at the console. So I couldn't replicate your situation. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike - How can you tell the Google Doc was created? Shouldn't it be saved to MY Google Drive?

Comment: @Daveh0 I cannot understand about your replying. In my test, I copied and pasted your script in my script editor and deploy Web Apps. Then, I requested the deployed Web Apps by my browser. By this flow, I could confirm that the script worked. Can I ask you about the reason that the Google Document is created in your Google Drive? If I misunderstood your question and reply comments, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike - my bad. Sorry I thought you were making a request to MY script URL, but I think you're saying you created and deployed your own? That makes more sense. I'm confused then. The script works when I test it from the webapp deployment dialog... just not from my actual webapp. Would you post your html/javascript and Google App Script in a Fiddle or somewhere I can copy and paste exactly from and into a new project? Thanks!

Comment: @Daveh0 I could understand about it. I didn't test for the endpoint of your deployed Web Apps. Because I wanted to test the script by including the settings of Web Apps. About the script I tested, Google Apps Script is the same with your script in your question. Javascript is almost the same with your script. I modified ``gurl`` to my endpoint and include jQuery. By this condition, I couldn't replicate your situation.

Comment: @Daveh0 I would like to confirm about your situation. 1. When you directly access to your Web Apps using your browser, the script of Web Apps works. 2. When you request with Javascript, the script doesn't work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194917/discussion-between-tanaike-and-daveh0).

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a script from an external location like your web app you need to follow some set-up and use the Script API. The documentation provided below has a great example on how to run your scripts from outside.

Additionally, you can use the APIs directly, with services like OAuth to use the APIs directly in a way that can save you some time and make your code more simple. Using OAuth can provide you with simple API requests. To use it:

- Go to the link provided below, select the desired scope (Drive for this example).
- Exchange the authorization token for refresh/access tokens.
- Proceed to configure the request. Here you can set all the parameters for the request, and even select from the existing operations the scope has available (“List possible operations” button).
- The resulting request will look like the one below:

  GET /drive/v3/files HTTP/1.1 Host: www.googleapis.com Content-length:
  0 Authorization: Bearer [YOUR-TOKEN]
- Beneath it you will see the server response to the request.

Documentation URL: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute

OAuth Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/